# C# quick question regarding "this" keyword?

Tags: c#

Is this piece of code correct:

```
using (MyForm form = new MyForm { TopMost = TopMost})
{
}
```

I want to make the new Form TopMost, if the parent Form is TopMost, or should I write like this, I mean the new Form TopMost property is not self assigned to itself.

```
using (MyForm form = new MyForm { TopMost = this.TopMost})
{
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the same, but the second is slightly more readable. Resharper will flag `this.` as redundant code, so to each his own.

Comment: Ya CodeRush also flagging this as redundant, so just wanted to cross check, whether is really redundant, or can cause any issues, where the new Form TopMost is assigned to itself.

Answer (score 1):

It also always happens when you have a property named exactly like an enum..

```
enum Reason { ... }

class Test
{
  Reason Reason { get; set; }
}
```

Like Yuriy said, this is just a readability issue for some

I say for some, because the side of the assignment tells us what the keyword refer to... a property or a variable, etc. So you usually deduce it without even thinking about it.

Mike